# Save activity state(not just some variables) on orientation change

Tags: android, android-activity, savestate

I realized that there are lots of question on this topic already asked on SO.
But I don't even know the basic when it comes to **saving the state of an activity**.

> ---

(Refer Screenshot Below) When app launches,

1) ScrollView item 1,2,3,4 are visible

2) table containd data which is populated due to Gainer button.

> ---

As showed in below screenshots, **While app is running in PORTRAIT mode**, I

1)scrolled down to ScrollView item 4,5,6

2)pressed the Loser button so accordingly data in the table below the button changes.

3)I'll even change content of graph dynamically(which I had not done yet).

> ---

**Now I switch to LANDSCAPE Mode** so

1)ScrollView is showing ScrollView item 1,2,3,4

2)table is showing data which is populated due to pressing Gainer button.

3)graph is as it is as I've not changed it yet(which I will change later).

> ---

So what happens is when I change the orientation, my activity is getting re-launched. So if user is performing some task in one orientation and he changes the orientation, then whole progress will be lost.

I know I need to save the state of the activity and Restore it when orientation changes.
But I don't know from where to start and what to save.

**ANY HELP WILL BE LIFE-SAVER !**

[image: Scrrenshot]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Option #1: Override `onSaveInstanceState()` of your `Activity` and put whatever information you want in the supplied `Bundle`. Your new activity instance will receive that `Bundle` in `onRestoreInstanceState()` (or `onCreate()`). [Here is a sample project demonstrating this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Rotation/RotationOne).

Option #2: Override `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` of your `Activity` and return some object that represents your state. Your new activity instance can call `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` to retrieve that object, so the new activity can apply that information. Be careful, though, not to have the old activity return something in the object that holds a reference back to the old activity (e.g., a widget, an instance of a regular inner class). [Here is a sample project demonstrating this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Rotation/RotationTwo).

Option #3: Convert this activity to a fragment. Have the fragment call `setRetainInstance(true);` on itself during its initial setup. Add the fragment dynamically to some activity via a `FragmentTransaction`. Now, when the configuration changes, the fragment is retained, so all your widgets and state are retained. [Here is an overly-complex sample application demonstrating this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Honeycomb/WeatherFragment).

Those are the three recommended approaches nowadays.